# Android Studio Changing Button Background Color

Tags: android-studio, background, background-color

I have started learning Android Studio and I am trying to change my button's background, but it is just not working.
Here is my code:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:text="salam"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#ffccee"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    />
```

The background color stays the same after I change it.

Comment: hello welcome to stackoverflow. have you tried to change your button style to @style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So actually for some reason now Button only follows the colour which is in the theme of your activity but instead of going and messing with theme use AppCompatButton

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="salam"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#ffccee"           
        android:background="#ffffff">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
```

Keep in mind even in future I would recommend using AppCompatButton.